# Is it possible to solve an equation with two unknowns? (Only one equation is given)

Tags: linear-algebra

So is there any equation (only one is given) with 2 unknowns, possible to solve and with finite number of solutions?. And if it is could you tell me how to solve it? (Sorry if tags are wrong, but I’m beginner in math.)

Comment: Can you share an example of an equation you are trying to solve?

Comment: Over the real numbers, $5x^2+y^2+12x+36+4xy=0$ has a unique solution $(x,y)=(-6,3)$

Comment: @CameronWilliams I can’t think of any but does $$\pi x + \frac{1}{2}y = 0$$ has finite number of solutions?

Comment: @Eminem1109 That's the equation of a line in standard form, $a x + b y = c$, with $(a, b) \neq (0, 0)$, so it has infinitely many solutions, say, $(x, y) = (x, -2\pi x)$ for all real $x$.

Comment: For any real $a, b$, the equation $(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = 0$ has unique solution $(x, y) = (a, b)$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen  $(x,y)=(-6,3)$ seems NOT a solution of the equation $5x^2+y^2+12x+36+4xy=0$. Would you mind to make a double check ?

Comment: @Eminem1109 You may like to learn something about "Diophantine equation" which deals with integer solutions of this kind equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limiting solutions to real numbers, the following equation with two variables has exactly seven solutions:

$$\bigl[(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)(x-7)\bigr]^2+y^2=0$$

The seven solutions are:

$$(x,y) = (1,0), \ (2,0), \ (3,0), \ ... \ (7,0)$$

The above equation can be easily modified to have an arbitrarily large (but finite) number of solutions.

Answer (score 4):

If you work over the field $\mathbb R$ of real numbers, then the positive elements of $\mathbb R$ are closed under addition and multiplication, and  moreover the product of two negative elements is positive, so that, over $\mathbb R$, a sum of square $a_1^2+a_2^2\ldots +a_k^2$ can only be a non-negative number. Thus an equation of the form $a_1^2+\ldots a_k^2=0$ implies that $a_i^2=0$ for all $i$, $1\leq i\leq k$, and $a_i^2 =0$ if any only if $a_i=0$.

This is the phenomenon behind the examples given in the comments above. If you work over the rational numbers the same trick is available to you, but over an algebraically closed field such as $\mathbb C$, tricks of this kind will not be available.

Comment: Sorry for asking (I’m beginner in math) what number below exponent (in this case: i,k, and 1) means?

Comment: @Eminem1109: I wrote $a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots a_k^2$ rather than $x^2+y^2+...$ -- the subscript $i$ or $k$ just indicates a new variable: if I want to write a point in 3-dimensional space then calling its coordinates $(x,y,z)$ works well, but if I need 8 dimensions then it is more common to write $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8)$ instead of running out of alphabet, and in fact people will usually abbreviate to $(x_1\ldots,x_8)$ or something similar.